# gpg trust like an CA cert

Tags: security, gpg

I am looking at setting up a GPG keyserver and I was wondering if it is possible to use GPG trust as TLS certificates are used. For example, the company GPG key is used to sign the department GPG key, which signs the user GPG key.

Would this work, or did I get the hole GPG thing wrong?

Comment: Trusting in someone's key is not the same as signing a certificate. If you would like to use "something like certificates", I highly recommend you to use certificates.

Answer (score 3):

You ask if "this would work", but you give no use case of what you want to achieve with your infrastructure.

Since you compare GPG keys to certificates, I assume you have a basic understanding of cryptography, but not enough to "connect the dots", so to speak.

**What signing somebody else's key means**

[The GNU Privacy Handbook](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x334.html) has an excellent entry, explaining the concept of "trust". The main idea of GPG public keys is that one person or entity has one or more keys. It is, however, impossible to tell if a given GPG key you find actually belongs to the person they claim to be.

For instance, I could create a keypair in the name of Donald Trump, and you have no way of knowing if the public key actually belonged to him or not.

As such, the "web of trust" was developed. The basic idea is to meet with a person in-person or any other verifiable channel and confirm that their public key is actually theirs. Sometimes users meet in large groups and all sign each other's keys, which is called a [Key Signing Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signing_party).

The basic idea is that, while you might not trust me, you might trust a friend of mine, who verified me. And if you don't trust that friend of mine, you can always trust a friend of his, and so on.

Does that mean all you have to do is create a ton of fake keys and all sign each other for instant credibility? No, because you trust none of these people, and their signatures are basically worthless to you.

**What a certificate means**

Certificates are similar in design. They take a public key, verify it and sign it. The big difference is that these signatures are not designed to build a chain between the person you wish to verify and you, but between the person you wish to verify and a certificate authority which you trust.

The whole process begins by an authority generating a "root certificate", which then in turn generates intermediate certificates, which are then used to sign your key and thus generate a certificate for you.

The advantage is that trust is not dependent on how big your web of trust is, but instead of which "Root Certificate Authorities" you trust. In general, you trust the CA's which get shipped with your operating system, because the company or group who makes your operating system trusts these certificates.

---

So, which one should you use? It highly depends on what your application is. If you wish to set up a GPG key server and give every employee a keypair and then have everybody sign everybody else, you can do that.

However, if you wish to do anything in the realms of authentification, then you are just much better off generating a Root CA yourself, deploying it on every machine in your company and signing the certificates from there.

Comment: Thank you for this.

I was confused on GPG and the trust ideas on signing keys.

Comment: @nig007 The documentation I have linked in my answer is a very good source on how to understand GPG better

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes, but long answer is that you propably need to learn about GPG a *lot* more. Passing trust transitively is an essential feature of GPG (called web of trust) and is therefore much more complex and configurable than in X509 PKI certificates (it's what you call TLS). The main difference between those technologies is that PKI relies on global, well known authorities whereas GPG expects everybody to define their own authorities for themselves (very simplified explanation). As an example of how flexible the web of trust is, see chapter "Using trust to validate keys" in [GnuPG handbook](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html)

Also I don't know what connection your question have to the stated goal of establishing your own keyserver and I should warn you that with that level of understanding it might be dangerous for you.

Comment: Thanks Yes i mean X509 certificates.

What i am trying to sort out or even work out if its possible

Root PKI/GPG -> Team PKI/GPG -> user PKI/GPG

So for example, 
allow the Dev team to sign a docker image and work on the Docker dev server.

But not allow Dev team to sign a docker image and work on the Docker live server.

Comment: `The main difference between those technologies is that PKI relies on global, well known authorities` that statement isn't technically accurate. This is they way we *use* the technology in the most obvious user facing settings such as web browsing, but it's not actually a feature of the technology. There are plenty of other common applications where just one (not globally known) CA will be accepted as an authority. EG In IOT it's common enough for the vendor to act as their own CA and all IOT devices only accept the vendor's CA certificate.